# What kind of terminal block is this?

Tags: terminology, terminal, terminal-block

I've perused a few resources (linked below) trying to learn more about this strip / block, but they mostly have side views / cross sections. I just want to know what the things in this picture are called so I can replace them -- starting with the parts of the terminal block / strip itself.

https://www.c3controls.com/white-paper/applications-of-electrical-terminal-blocks-in-industrial-automation/

https://realpars.com/terminal-blocks/#

[image]

EDIT: Here are my thoughts so far:

The white strips running horizontally along the middle are jumpers -- they connect wires of the same number label. The taller blocks on the middle-left are type 3C. The entire strip is mounted on a 35 mm DIN rail.

Comment: Have you checked with Phoenix contact?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are [rail-mounted feed-through push-in terminal blocks](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us/?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=3248100&library=usen&pcck=P-15-02-12-01&tab=1&selectedCategory=ALL). You can get them for all kinds of rail systems, the ones I've linked to are for NS15 rails.

Answer (score 2):

I call these "DIN rail terminal blocks".  They are made by Phoenix Contact, Weidmuller, and probably others.

If you look on the maker's or distributor's web sites, you will find a wide variety of terminal configurations, and associated hardware, such as the bussing/jumper rails you mention.

Answer (score 1):

The general term is "din rail terminals". Well-known manufacturers include Pheonix Contact, Weidmuller and Wago, there are probablly others.

In addition to the regular terminals you will nearly always have.

- End covers and/or partition plates, din rail terminals are usually insulated on one side, but have metal exposed on the other. So covers are needed at the end of a run or when changing between different sizes of terminal. Sometimes it is also nessacery to provide extra insulation or useful to provide visual seperation between different groups of terminals.
- End stops, din rail terminals clip to the din rail and slide easily along it. To keep the terminals arranged neatly and safely on the rail end stops are used. These generally have screws that are used to clamp them tightly to the din rail and prevent the devices from sliding.
- Jumpers/Bridges these are used to connect terminals together. They are usually designed so it is possible to skip over positions by removing pins from the bridge, most din rail terminals have two rows of jumper slots allowing bridges to be joined end to end or allowing two bridges to be run in paralell (say one for live and one for neutral). Some manufacturers even make wire bridges giving even more flexible terminals.
- Earth terminals, these normally connect electrically to the DIN rail, so all the earth connections are automatically commoned without the need for explict jumpers. These are usually colored "green+yellow" though exactly what that means seems to vary by brand. Some have very visible striping, others seem to have a much more subtle "mottled" effect.

There are many variations, different sizes, different types of termination, multi-level terminals to save space on the din rail (at the cost of greater height), terminals with disconnecting means, terminals with support for high-current busbars, terminals with fuses and more.

In my experiance the maker's websites invariably suck. They provide a bunch of technical data on the individual products but are very bad for figuring out the system as a whole. You will want to find the catalogue PDFs and use them in conjunction with the website.